# XCode 6: Unable to create watchpoint

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, lldb

I am trying to watch the following variable

```
vector<Vec3f> lines[2];
```

in XCode (where `Vec3f` is an OpenCV datatype, a vector of 3 floats).
But when I right-click the variable in Variable View and choose `Watch "lines"`, I am being yelled at by XCode:

> error: Watchpoint creation failed (addr=0x16fd92d48, size=48, variable
>   expression='lines'). error: watch size of 48 is not supported

This seems to happen with other variables of type `vector<T>` as well, but only if it is a local variable. I can watch the `vector` passed in as a method parameter just fine.

```
double computeReprojectionError(vector<Point2f>& imgpts1, vector<Point2f>&   imgpts2, Mat& inlier_mask, const Mat& F)
{
                                              // ^ I can watch this guy
    vector<Vec3f> lines[2]; // <- I cannot watch this guy (size 48)

    vector<Point2f> imgpts1_copy(npt), // <- I cannot watch this guy (size 24)
    imgpts2_copy(npt);

...
```

I googled the error with no success. Can somebody shed light on the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watchpoints are in general fairly limited resources.  You didn't say what architecture you were debugging, but x86_64, for instance, has only 4 hardware watchpoint registers, which can at most watch 8 bytes each.  So you wouldn't be able to watch a 48 byte region on x86_64 in any case.

But you should be able to watch a 24 byte region by using 3 8-byte watches.  I tried this locally, and it looks like there is a bug in the watchpoint setting - it doesn't divvy up a request larger than the native watchpoint size into several smaller watches.  So you have to break up the request into 1/2/4/8 byte chunks by hand.

I filed a bug to track this with the Apple bug reporter.  But if you want to track it feel free to file one at Apple's http://bugreporter.apple.com site if you want to track the resolution of this, and I'll dup mine to it.